# How to handle PointerEvent for stylus and touch at the same time?

Tags: javascript, pointer-events

I tried to use Pointer Events to handle both stylus pen and finger touch simultaneously on touchscreen like phone, tablet. The use case is when drawing using pen, user can use finger for quick gestures. However, when pen is touched, and then finger touched the screen, only the pen touch will be recognize, not the finger touches. But when finger touches is captured first, then pen touches the screen, pointerdown triggered for both.

Thanks all!

Comment: Question is unclear, please use edit feature

Comment: @ZachJensz hi, what I meant was "pointerdown" will trigger for multiple fingers, but when I use a stylus pen first, and touch a finger, it will only recognize the pen, not the fingers.